# ImportError: cannot import name doccer

Tags: python, python-2.7, scipy, spyder, pythonxy

I just installed `python xy 2.7.9` on `Windows 7`. I went to run some previously written code in `Spyder` which calls:

```
from scipy.sparse import linalg as sla
```

However, I get the following error:

```
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\scipy\sparse\linalg\__init__.py", line 113, in <module>
from .matfuncs import *

File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\scipy\sparse\linalg\matfuncs.py", line 20, in <module>
import scipy.misc

File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\scipy\misc\__init__.py", line 44, in <module>
from . import doccer

ImportError: cannot import name doccer
```

Does anyone know how to fix this? I find this weird because it worked with my previous copy of Python (which I uninstalled before installing the new version).

Thanks!

Comment: It appears the scipy that comes with PythonXY is incomplete. You could try and take this up with the PythonXY maintainers/mailing list. Alternatively, if PythonXY comes with pip, you could try and installing scipy through pip: `pip install --force-reinstall scipy` to get the missing module.

Answer (score 1):

What worked for me is moving doccer.py from "misc" folder to "_lib" folder (which are in path /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/scipy/ for me).
I found this in a release note of scipy : https://github.com/scipy/scipy/pull/9652